# Do we get all the data with createMediaStreamSource in webaudio?

Tags: javascript, real-time, web-audio-api, microphone

I am using webaudio with javascript, and this simple example (to be used with google-chrome),

https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~faure/enseignement/javascript/code/web_audio/ex_microphone_to_array/

the data are collected from the microphone into an array, in real time.
Then we compare the true time (`t1`) with the time spent by the data (`t2`) and they differ by a fixed ratio `t2/t1 = 1.4`.

Remark: here, true time t1 means the duration time measured by the clock,i.e. obtained by the function Date().getTime();, whereas 
time t2 = N*Dt where N is the number of data obtained from the microphone and Dt=1/(Sample rate) = 1/44100 sec.  is the time between two data.

My question is: does it mean that the sample data rate is not **44100Hz** but **30700Hz*2** (i.e. with two channels)?
or they are some repetitions within the data?

Another related question please: is there a way to check that during such a real time acquisition process,  we have not lost any data?

Comment: What does "true time" and "time spent by the data" mean?  On my machine `t2/t1 = 1.3` or so.

Comment: Remark: here, true time t1 means the duration time measured by the clock,i.e. obtained by the function Date().getTime();, whereas 
time t2 = N*Dt where N is the number of data obtained from the microphone and Dt=1/(Sample rate) = 1/44100 sec.  is the time between two data.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at your test code, you are using an `AnalyserNode` to determine `t2`, and you call the function `F3()` via rAF.  This happens about every 16.6 ms or 732 samples (at 44.1 kHz).  But you increment t2 by N = 1024 frames each time.  Hence your t2 value is about 1.4 times larger than the actual number of frames.  (Which is what you're actually getting!)

If you really want to measure how many samples you've received you have to do synchronously in the audio graph so use either a `ScriptProcessorNode` or an `AudioWorklet` to count how many samples of data have been processed.  You can then increment t2 by the correct amount.  This should match your t1 values more closely.  But note that the clock that drives the t1 value is very likely different from the audio clock that drives the audio system.  They will drift over time, although the drift is probably pretty small as long as you don't run this for days at a time.